# Starting a node.js server

Tags: javascript, node.js

I recently got into node and I installed it on my localhost. I am using WAMP. I am on Windows Vista.

Anwyay, I installed it. I made a new file in my localhost directory with this being called `server.js`

```
var http = require('http');

http.createServer(function (request, response) {
    response.writeHead(200, {
        'Content-Type': 'text/plain',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' : '*'
    });
    response.end('Hello World\n');
}).listen(1337);
```

then I went to node and tried typing `% node server.js` and all I got was an ellipses. What gives?

---

**UPDATE:** I checked my Systems variable and saw that my `PATH` lists the node.js as `C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\`

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "an ellipses"? Could you show us the literal output after you hit Return? FWIW, the code as shown works for me.

Comment: Did you hit localhost:1337 ? What content is there?

Comment: I get `Oops! Google Chrome could not connect to localhost:1337`. However `localhost` seems to connect just fine as I can see the WAMP page on `localhost`

Comment: @dwerner I edited my question to add the picture.

Comment: the code works fine for me. what do you get on running 'node server.js'

Comment: On windows hit "windows key + R" then type "cmd" then enter `C:\path\to\your\nodejs\node.exe C:\path\to\your\nodejs\app\server.js` if your on windows and don't have any of the `PATH` variables configured

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Run `cmd` and then run `node server.js`. In your example, you are trying to use the REPL to run your command, which is not going to work. The ellipsis is node.js expecting more tokens before closing the current scope (you can type code in and run it on the fly here)

Comment: `Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\server.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:289:25)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:467:10)
    at startup (node.js:136:18)
    at node.js:963:3`

Comment: And your pwd is? Where is your server.js?

Answer (score 0):

The NodeJS code that you wrote is corrected, and it should work but as @dwerner said you have to write `node server.js` in the command prompt not inside the Node REPL.

But today most of who work with NodeJS are developing using a development environment (IDE). By using IDE you get a hotkey for running your code, and many things that can help you in the daily development (Syntax highlight for e.g.)

One of the most popular IDE's today for NodeJS development is VSCode, you can check it out.

Answer (score 0):

As dwerner and aminadav mentioned, you need to run the node command for the main .js file you're using for your script/app. This file will typically be index.js by default, when you run `npm init` to create the package.json for your NodeJS project.

Maybe you will find this blog post that covers the basics helpful as well. :)
https://dev.to/bishopwm/my-first-server-and-rest-api-essentials-for-frontenders-2gnk